# Is it safe to delete a Django QuerySet that may be empty?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Is it safe to attempt to delete a QuerySet that might be empty? In other words, if  I am not sure if the name "MJ" exists, is there any functional difference between these 2 approaches? Is either preferred?

1)

```py
query = m.objects.filter(name="MJ")
if query.exists():
    query.get().delete()
```

2. 

```py
m.objects.filter(name="MJ").delete()
```

Comment: In this query, you tried to retrieve all the objects in your model m that have `"MJ"` as value for the `name` field. So, if by safe you mean "am I going to destroy my model?" no, you won't find problems.

However, are you sure you are not going to remove other information contained in other fields of your model? I would go for a check first.

Comment: The second approach is better you can also do `m.objects.filter(name="MJ").first().delete()` that will delete the first occurrence of instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. The `.get()` will try to retrieve a *single* object, and it will raise an error if there are *multiple* such objects.

Furthermore if there is only one record, the first variant will make three queries: first check if there exists *at least* one record, then fetch that record, and then finally make a delete call, which can also result in delete triggers.

The second will fetch the primary keys of the objects it will remove, run delete triggers and finally remove these objects. It is thus more efficient. Furthermore if no such record exists, or multiple objects with `MJ` as `name`, it will remove these objects, so it is less error prone and more efficient.